# C++ access a mapped file throughout entire dll

Tags: c++, global-variables

I want to map a file and use it throughout the entire dll. 
The dll consists of several classes that are linked to each other.

For example startclass.someclass.someotherclass

someotherclass should also be able to access the mapped file.
I map the file in "startclass".

To access the mapped file also from within "someotherclass", I added a new class named "global.cpp" to my project.

In "global.h" I have stated

```
    HANDLE                  m_hVoiceData;
    void*                   m_pVoiceData;
```

Now in "someotherclass" I want to access the mapped file.
Therefore I have said

```
#include "global.h"
```

But when I now try to do the following from within "someotherclass"...

```
memcpy(nEncodedBytes,(void*)m_pVoiceData[iFirstByteToRead], iLenCompressedBytes);
```

.... the compiler tells me that "Expression needs to be a pointer to completed object type".

Can somebody tell me where I went wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `m_pVoiceData` is already a void pointer the cast in `(void*)m_pVoiceData[iFirstByteToRead]` is redundant. However, as explained by Mats Petersson you cannot index into a `void*`.

You can either change `m_pVoiceData` to a char* then use

```
memcpy(nEncodedBytes,(void*)(&m_pVoiceData[iFirstByteToRead]),iLenCompressedBytes)  // the cast to void is now required
```

Alternatively, if you cannot change this header use

```
memcpy(nEncodedBytes, &((char*)(pVoiceData))[iFirstByteToRead],iLenCompressedBytes);
```

Comment: note: use c++ style casts since you're using c++, above is using c-style casts so that it's easier to understand if you're not familiar with c++ casts

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my code according to &((char*), but when I try to compile it, the compiler says "m_pVoiceData" is already defined in audiodata.obj.

Comment: that means that `m_pVoiceData` is already defined in audiodata compilation unit (probably audiodata.cpp). is  `m_pVoiceData` in a class or is it a global variable?

Comment: It is in the header of global.h. I have placed it somewhere else, and now it is working, at least compiling. I will test it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can't index into a `void *`. Instead, you will need to use `char *m_pVoiceData` (and a `m_pVoiceData = reinterpret_cast<char *>(stuff);` instead of `m_pVoiceData = stuff;` where your data is being mapped.

Comment: Is that due to my making the 2 variables public, or is it because of my use of memcpy? I am asking because the void* m_pVoiceData is from a samplecode from Microsoft.

Comment: It is due to `m_pVoiceData[iFirstByteToRead]` - `void` doesn't have a size, so how far into `m_pVoiceData` is `iFirstByteToRead`? `iFirstByteToRead * sizeof(void)` isn't clearly defined, so you can't do that.

Comment: m_pVoiceData[iFirstByteToRead] was just my newbie attempt to read a certain amount of bytes from a certain position. Can you suggest a simpler solution where I don't have to change anything else but just this line? I don't want to change the MS code if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I probably should delete this answer then.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't understand where you suggested a change. Should I change something in the code where the file is mapped? Or in the line where I read the bytes? Or in both?

Comment: Change your declaration in `global.h`, and then change where the compile complains "assigning void * to char *" or something like that.

Comment: "Expression needs to be a pointer to completed object type" means that you are "trying to use an object of type void", as far as I can tell.

Comment: But I would like to keep the MS code if possible. I think that simply my line where I read the bytes is simply wrong. This is how I declared nEncodedBytes: nEncodedBytes = new unsigned char[iLenCompressedBytes]; Does this help?

Comment: This:     HANDLE                  m_hVoiceData;
    void*                   m_pVoiceData;

Comment: Ok, so use `reinterpret_cast<char *>(pVoiceData)[iFirstByteToRead]` in the memcpy line. It would have been REALLY helpful if you explained in the original question that "global.h" can't be modified.

Comment: Okay, thanks and sorry for the confusion. It was quite difficult to explain it at all.